# How to use array_merge

Tags: php, array-merge

I'm trying to merge 2 array form one key *(idhprim)*, but I don't know how to do. I try many array function but no way to the job !
Please can you help me ?

I had this:

```
    $libelle = [
          'Hématies' => [0 =>  2, 1 =>  413, 2 =>  526, 3 =>  1481, 4 =>  1551],
          'Hémoglobine' => [0 =>  3, 1 =>  245, 2 =>  1552],
          'Hématocrite' => [0 =>  4, 1 =>  246, 2 =>  414, 3 =>  1553]
    ];

    $resultats = [
          '0' => [
              'id' =>  '880621',
              'id_hprim' =>  '413',
              'id_apicrypt' =>  '26818',
              'res_1' =>  '12',
              'normalite' =>  'N',
              'res_2' =>  '0'
          ],
          1 => [
              'id' =>  '880622',
              'id_hprim' =>  '526',
              'id_apicrypt' =>  '26818',
              'res_1' =>  '3.2',
              'normalite' =>  'N',
              'res_2' =>  '0'
          ],
          2 => [
              'id' =>  '880623',
              'id_hprim' =>  '3',
              'id_apicrypt' =>  '26818',
              'res_1' =>  '13',
              'normalite' =>  'N',
              'res_2' =>  '0'
          ],
          3 => [
              'id' =>  '880624',
              'id_hprim' =>  '414',
              'id_apicrypt' =>  '26818',
              'res_1' =>  '35',
              'normalite' =>  'N',
              'res_2' =>  '0'
          ],
          4 => [
              'id' =>  '880625',
              'id_hprim' =>  '245',
              'id_apicrypt' =>  '26818',
              'res_1' =>  '11.7',
              'normalite' =>  'N',
              'res_2' =>  '0'
          ]
    ];
```

and I would like to have :

```
    $libelle = [
          'Hématies' => [
              0 => [
                  'id' =>  '880621',
                  'id_hprim' =>  '413',
                  'id_apicrypt' =>  '26818',
                  'res_1' =>  '12',
                  'normalite' =>  'N',
                  'res_2' =>  '0'  
              ],
              1 => [
                  'id' =>  '880622',
                  'id_hprim' =>  '526',
                  'id_apicrypt' =>  '26818',
                  'res_1' =>  '3.2',
                  'normalite' =>  'N',
                  'res_2' =>  '0'
              ]
          ],
          'Hémoglobine' => [
              0 = [
                  'id' =>  '880623',
                  'id_hprim' =>  '3',
                  'id_apicrypt' =>  '26818',
                  'res_1' =>  '13',
                  'normalite' =>  'N',
                  'res_2' =>  '0'  
              ]
          ],
          'Hématocrite' => [
            0 = [
                  'id' =>  '880624'
                  'id_hprim' =>  '414'
                  'id_apicrypt' =>  '26818'
                  'res_1' =>  '14/03/19'
                  'normalite' =>  'N'
                  'res_2' =>  '0'
            ]  
          ],
          ....
    ]
```

So I tried like this but it doesn't work :

```
foreach ($libelle as $key=>$val) {
foreach ($val as $v) {
    if (($k = array_search($v, array_column($resultats, 'id_hprim'))) !== false) {
        $val = array_merge($val, $resultats[$k]);
    }
}}var_dump($libelle);
```

Comment: give more explanation to your question ,What is the condition for merrging that two arrays?

Comment: The logic in your question is unclear. Why does the 3rd item of $resultats goes to $libelle['Hémoglobine'][0] ?

Comment: The code protions were just an example. I have an array of biological results over several days with several values. I would like to group these values into one array, sorting by order of desired wording, knowing that several different id_hprim correspond to the same label ... Hemoglobin, Hematocrit etc ...
I do not know if I'm clear enough.
@Macmuri: the value from "245" should be inside the final array but omitted from the example in the statement by mistake (This is not the goal).

Comment: Try this solution: replace "$val = array_merge($val, $resultats[$k]);" with      $ind = array_search($v,$libelle[$key]);
  $libelle[$key][$ind] = $resultats[$k];  Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Great ! You find it. Thank you very much.